# batch converting mp4 to avi

Tags: matlab, mp4, avi

I'm trying to convert a bunch of mp4 files to avis using the code below. I know that the conversion works as I've verified it on single files. However when I try to read in all mp4s from a directory the 'files' struct I've tried to create is empty. I'm relatively new to programming in MatLab so I'm sure I'm making many silly errors. How can I properly load in and iterate over multiple mp4 files in order to convert them all to avis? Thanks!

NB: I have tried different methods of conversion, but MatLab seems to be the best at ensuring no size or quality distortion.

```
files = dir(fullfile('E:\Heather\Summer2013\*.mp4'));
for i = 1:length(files)
filename = files(i).name;

    %create objects to read and write the video
    readerObj = VideoReader('files(i).name.mp4');
    writerObj = VideoWriter('files(i).name.avi','Uncompressed AVI');

    %open AVI file for writing
    open(writerObj);

    %read and write each frame
    for k = 1:readerObj.NumberOfFrames
       img = read(readerObj,k);
       writeVideo(writerObj,img);
    end
    close(writerObj);
end
```

Answer (score 2):

A call to `dir` produces a struct array where file names are stored as strings in the `name` field.  That is, `files(i).name` contains a string. To use it,

```
readerObj = VideoReader(files(i).name); % no quotes, no extension
```

To write with a different file extension, determine the file base with `fileparts` and add the .avi extension.  For example:

```
>> str = 'mymovie.mp4';
>> [~,fileBase,fileExt] = fileparts(str)
fileBase =

mymovie

fileExt =

.mp4

>> writerObj = VideoWriter([fileBase '.avi'],'Uncompressed AVI');
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to read the file with the name `('files(i).name.mp4')` which obviously not exists. `filename` should be the corret parameter for the reader, for the writer you have to replace the extension.